# How to use setDoc with Firebase-Admin with Typescript in firestore?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have `config/firebase.ts`:

```
import { initializeApp, cert } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'

const firebaseAdminApp = initializeApp({
    credential: cert({
        privateKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
        clientEmail: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_SERVICE_EMAIL,
        projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
    }),
    databaseURL: `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}.firebaseio.com`
});


const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseAdminApp);

export default firestore
```

and when trying to upsert, I have:

```
import firestore from "../config/firebaseAdmin";

const upsertInstance = async (instance: Instance) => {
  const hashedUri = createHash('sha256').update(instance.uri).digest('hex')
  const res = await firestore.doc(`instances/${hashedUri}`).set(instance);
  return res
}
```

but I get:

```
Error: expected a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Firebase Admin is not totally modular yet. Are you importing `setDoc()` and `doc()` from `"firebase/firestore"`? Please share the complete code including the imports.

Comment: Yup - updated the question to reflect imports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Admin is not totally modular yet like the client SDK yet so you would have to use namespaced syntax. Admin SDK's Firestore instance won't work perfectly with client SDK functions. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
export const db = getFirestore(firebaseAdminApp);
```

```
import { db } from "../path/to/firebase"

const upsertInstance = async (instance: Instance) => {
  const res = await db.doc(`instances/${instance.uri}`).set(instance);
  return res;
}
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js_5) for more information.

Comment: I get `Error: expected a function`

Comment: @Shamoon can you please update your question with the latest code that you tried? Please share all the imports as well

Comment: Updated - please check

Comment: @Shamoon the error seems to be related to `update(instance.uri)` or can you please check error logs and find the line that is issue?

Comment: The line is: `const res = await firestore.doc(`instances/${hashedUri}`).set(instance);` that's the issue apparently

Comment: @Shamoon the code is correct. In that case, can you please tell me what is `instance`? Best to `console.log(hashedUri, instance)` and share a screenshot of the output .